# How to convert Excel file into cucumber DataTable

Tags: cucumber, bdd, cucumber-java

Hi I am doing a BDD Cucumber Project. Instead of providing the data in DataTable itself in cucumber feature file. I am trying to pass the Excel file location
My Cucumber feature file is something like this

```
Feature: Read data from cucumber Feature

Scenario: Any scenario with different set of excel data
Then Read the data from  excel sheet "C:\Users\Govind\Desktop\MOCK_DATA.xlsx"
```

Now what I want to do is in my steps definition I want to use some kind of excel reader to read the data of excel file and convert those data into Cucumber DataTable. So that I can use DataTable.asMaps on that. I have already implemented that But having problem in using .asMaps function on that DataTable.

My ExcelReader Class is

```
package otherutil;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelReaders {

    private String fileName;
    private String sheetName;
    private int sheetIndex;
    private XSSFWorkbook book;

    private ExcelReaders(ExcelReaderBuilder excelReaderBuilder) {
        this.fileName = excelReaderBuilder.fileName;
        this.sheetIndex = excelReaderBuilder.sheetIndex;
        this.sheetName = excelReaderBuilder.sheetName;
    }

    public static class ExcelReaderBuilder {

        private String fileName;
        private String sheetName;
        private int sheetIndex;

        public ExcelReaderBuilder setFileLocation(String location) {
            this.fileName = location;
            return this;
        }

        public ExcelReaderBuilder setSheet(String sheetName) {
            this.sheetName = sheetName;
            return this;
        }

        public ExcelReaderBuilder setSheet(int index) {
            this.sheetIndex = index;
            return this;
        }

        public ExcelReaders build() {
            return new ExcelReaders(this);
        }

    }

    private XSSFWorkbook getWorkBook(String filePath) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {
        return new XSSFWorkbook(new File(filePath));
    }

    private XSSFSheet getWorkBookSheet(String fileName, String sheetName) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {
        this.book = getWorkBook(fileName);
        return this.book.getSheet(sheetName);
    }

    private XSSFSheet getWorkBookSheet(String fileName, int sheetIndex) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {
        this.book = getWorkBook(fileName);
        return this.book.getSheetAt(sheetIndex);
    }

    public List<List<String>> getSheetData() throws IOException{
        XSSFSheet sheet;
        List<List<String>> outerList = new LinkedList<>();
        
        try {
            sheet = getWorkBookSheet(fileName, sheetName);
            outerList = getSheetData(sheet);
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }finally {
            this.book.close();
        }
        return outerList;
    }
    
    public List<List<String>> getSheetDataAt() throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {
        
        XSSFSheet sheet;
        List<List<String>> outerList = new LinkedList<>();
        
        try {
            sheet = getWorkBookSheet(fileName, sheetIndex);
            outerList = getSheetData(sheet);
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }finally {
            this.book.close();
        }
        return outerList;
    }

    private List<List<String>> getSheetData(XSSFSheet sheet) {
        List<List<String>> outerList = new LinkedList<>();
        prepareOutterList(sheet, outerList);
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(outerList);
    }

    private void prepareOutterList(XSSFSheet sheet, List<List<String>> outerList) {
        for (int i = sheet.getFirstRowNum(); i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
            List<String> innerList = new LinkedList<>();
            XSSFRow xssfRow = sheet.getRow(i);

            for (int j = xssfRow.getFirstCellNum(); j < xssfRow.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
                prepareInnerList(innerList, xssfRow, j);
            }
            outerList.add(Collections.unmodifiableList(innerList));
        }
    }

    private void prepareInnerList(List<String> innerList, XSSFRow xssfRow, int j) {
        switch (xssfRow.getCell(j).getCellType()) {

        case BLANK:
            innerList.add("");
            break;

        case STRING:
            innerList.add(xssfRow.getCell(j).getStringCellValue());
            break;

        case NUMERIC:
            innerList.add(xssfRow.getCell(j).getNumericCellValue() + "");
            break;

        case BOOLEAN:
            innerList.add(xssfRow.getCell(j).getBooleanCellValue() + "");
            break;

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot read the column : " + j);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my stepDefn class code

```
ExcelReaders readers = new ExcelReaders.ExcelReaderBuilder().setFileLocation(excelUrl).setSheet(0).build();
        List<List<String>> excelData=readers.getSheetDataAt();
        DataTable data = DataTable.create(excelData);
```

after that I want to use something like this so that I can get the data

```
for (Map<String, String> users : data.asMaps(String.class, String.class))) {


            System.out.println(users.get("email"));
            
            
        }
```

And My Excel file data is like this

[image]

But I am not bale to do. I find everywhere for help but could not get. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the `Transformer<T>` interface of cucumber and map the `List<List<String>>` to `DataTable`.  It works for me.
Such as:

```
import io.cucumber.cucumberexpression.Transformer


public class ExcelDataToDataTable extends Transformer<DataTable> {

    @Override
    public DataTable transform(String filePath) {
        ExcelReader reader = new ExcelReader.ExcelReaderBuilder()
                .setFileLocation(filePath)
                .setSheet(0)
                .build();
        
        List<List<String>> excelData = getExcelData(reader);
        
        List<DataTableRow> dataTableRows = getDataTableRows(excelData);
        
        DataTable table = getDataTable(dataTableRows);
        
        return table;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataTable.create(excelData) directly.
For that you need to

1. retrieve the data from excel
2. Convert to DataTable
   1:

   ```
   public static List<List<String>> readExcelFile(String filePath) {
    List<List<String>> data = new ArrayList<>();

    try (FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filePath)) {
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

            List<String> rowData = new ArrayList<>();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                switch (cell.getCellTypeEnum()) {
                    case STRING:
                        rowData.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                        break;
                    case NUMERIC:
                        rowData.add(String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
                        break;
                    case BOOLEAN:
                        rowData.add(String.valueOf(cell.getBooleanCellValue()));
                        break;
                    case BLANK:
                        rowData.add("");
                        break;
                    default:
                        rowData.add("");
                        break;
                }
            }
            data.add(rowData);
        }

        workbook.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return data;
   ```

   }

2:

```
public static DataTable excelDataToDataTable(String filePath) {
        List<List<String>> excelData = ExcelUtils.readExcelFile(filePath);
        DataTable dataTable = DataTable.create(excelData);
        return dataTable;
    }
```

This will do the job.